# Values ​of HTML elements lists and paginated with bootstrap + React are not saved after changing the page. React + Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, bootstrap-5

I have a "Pagination" Component, which is in charge of paginating items (usually questions of some kind of test) that are passed as parameters.
The pagination and drawing of the components on the screen according to the page.
As we can see, the element that makes use of Pagination passes a test array with a few questions, and indicates that it wants to make pages of 5 questions:

```
    const dataTest = [
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 1</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 2</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 3</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 4</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 5</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 6</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 7</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 8</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 9</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>
    ]
    const showPage =  () => {

    }

    return (
        <>
        <Paginacion elementsList={dataTest} currentPagePar={1} rangePagesPar={5} />
        data 
        </>

    )
```

Next, we have the Pagination Component, which makes use of a very simple helper subComponent
(written at the end) whose purpose is to save the ID to be able to list it well with .map. Here the whole component:

```
import { ReactDOM, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import React from "react"


export const Paginacion = ({elementsList, currentPagePar, rangePagesPar}) => {

    const [fullList, setFullList] = useState([])
    const [currentList, setCurrentList] = useState([])
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(currentPagePar)
    const [rangePages, setRangePages] = useState(rangePagesPar) //10 items per page.

    //use Effect load
    useEffect (() =>{
        const data = [];
        for (let index = 0; index <elementsList.length; index++){
            const current = <ElementoPaginacion element={elementsList[index]} key={index} />
            data.push(current);
        }
        setFullList(data);
    }
    ,[]);

    const changePage = (page) => {
        setCurrentPage (page);
    }

    useEffect(() =>{
        console.log ( currentPage * rangePages);
        console.log ((currentPage * rangePages) + rangePages);
        for (let index = currentPage * rangePages; index < (currentPage * rangePages) + rangePages; index++){
            console.log(fullList[index]);
        }

    }, [,currentPage]);


    return (
        <>
        {
            //Calculate init index (it depends ont the current page) to show the questions, and the number of elements to show (its rangePages)
            fullList.slice(currentPage * rangePages, (currentPage * rangePages) + rangePages).map((current) => (
                <React.Fragment key={current.key}>
                {current}
                </React.Fragment>
            ))
        }
        <nav>
            <ul className="pagination">
                {
                    (() => {
                        //Draw pages numbers.
                        let valD = fullList.length;
                        let totalPages = valD / rangePages;
                        if (valD%rangePages !=0) totalPages += 1;
                        const retArray = [];
                        retArray.push(<li key={"\"init\""} className="page-item"><a className="page-link" aria-label="Previous" href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span></a></li>);
                        if (valD%rangePages !=0) totalPages += 1;
                        for (let index = 0; index < totalPages; index ++){                            
                            retArray.push(
                                <li key={index} className="page-item"><a className="page-link" href="#" onClick={() => changePage(index)}>{index}</a></li>                                
                            );
                        }
                        retArray.push(<li key={"\"end\""} className="page-item"><a className="page-link" aria-label="Next" href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span></a></li>);
                        return retArray;
                        
                    }                    
                    )()
                }
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </>
    )

}

const ElementoPaginacion = ({element}) =>{
    return(
        element
    )
}
```

As you can see, I create a  when starting the component (I use a useEffect only on load of the Pagination component, because if I don't, I can't assign a key to each element passed).
Once this is done, every time the page is changed, the snippet is executed:

```
        {
            //Calculate init index (it depends ont the current page) to show the questions, and the number of elements to show (its rangePages)
            fullList.slice(currentPage * rangePages, (currentPage * rangePages) + rangePages).map((current) => (
                <React.Fragment key={current.key}>
                {current}
                </React.Fragment>
            ))
        }
```

Which with a simple calculation, draws the elements correctly, with their checkboxes. The problem is when changing the page. I have attached some numerated screenshots so you can see the failure:

1. I am on page 0, I show the first questions.
2. I select some answers.
3. I go to the next page, page 1, and the questions on that page load correctly.
4. I try to go back to the previous page (0), and the results that I had marked are gone!!! Where are the boxes that I marked before passing page?

[image: Im at page 0]
[image: I mark some options in each question]
[image: I change page and I load new questions, still empty. Ok]
[image: Here comes the problem: the checked options have now reseted]
What am I doing bad? Should I manually set options when someone checks a checkbox? Why its not save in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You should always save your choice in state variable. Default value for checkbox is false, so when you re-render screen all checkboxes marked as false. You must use state to save your checkboxes states and mark checkboxes as checked={checkdox.id === selectedCheckboxes.id}

Comment: The problem is that this component has to be generic, capable of receiving any type of HTML without knowing the content. How can I save the content of a tag (all its HTML) using a useState?

Comment: It is depends on your realisation. You can use tag id in your solution. But more preferable way it past only data Map<id, string>() (for example) and generate html inside your component. If you want past different html elements then you should create every element as separated component and create generic component for that.